# JSTL if-then-else session attribute

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jstl

I am having some problems writing a if-then-else condition for my jsp page. I think the issue is with my quotes. Also is it possible to use JSTL in javascript?

**Code**

```
 <c:choose>
    <c:when test= "'<%=request.getSession().getAttribute("userName")%>' == Guest">
      <button class="btn" id="getCitizens" onclick="DoGuestAccess()" type="button">Guest Access</button>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
      <button class="btn" id="getCitizens" onclick="DoUsersAccess()" type="button">User Access</button>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

**Error**

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/jsp/newpage.jsp (line: 485, column: 71) equal symbol expected
```

Comment: no it's not. JSTL can only be interpreted on server side.

Comment: so i should pass the JSTL value into an html element and then use javascript to get the value from the element for the condition?

Comment: JSTL can be used to *render* JavaScript.

Comment: 2 solutions, either use JSTL to activate the correct js code based on the current session/parameters in a jsp, or use an ajax call to get the value from your servlets, looking at your current code, the first solution seems more appropriate.

Comment: @Farid i updated the code however i am having errors with the condition line i think i am typing it incorrectly? Can you assist

Comment: sorry i was away, glad you got it sorted with henry's post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a problem with the test expression, try this:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test= "${request.getSession().getAttribute("userName").equals("Guest")}">
        <button class="btn" id="getCitizens" onclick="DoGuestAccess()" type="button">Guest Access</button>
    </c:when>
<c:otherwise>
    <button class="btn" id="getCitizens" onclick="DoUsersAccess()" type="button">User Access</button>
</c:otherwise>
```

In addition Java uses the `equals` method for String comparison.

Or more verbose:

```
<% var userName = request.getSession().getAttribute("userName"); %>
<c:choose>
    <c:when test= "${userName.equals("Guest")}">
        <button class="btn" id="getCitizens" onclick="DoGuestAccess()" type="button">Guest Access</button>
    </c:when>
<c:otherwise>
    <button class="btn" id="getCitizens" onclick="DoUsersAccess()" type="button">User Access</button>
</c:otherwise>
```

Comment: yeah, the `${..}` is important, not sure about the quotes, sometimes escaping helps: "${userName.equals(\"Guest\")}". Single quotes are used for chars in java, but if it works, it works....